# ImportError: No module named web

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, web.py

I am getting this error in my `apache` error log file when I try to run my `web.py` application using `mod_wsgi`. I have installed `web.py` successfully on my shared hosting and I can confirm that I am able to import it locally:

```
>>> import web
>>> web.application(('/', 'test'), globals())
<web.application.application instance at 0x1f8d3b0>
```

I am also able to run the built in server and serve pages to my site successfully.

I can confirm that the `mod_wsgi` module is working in `apache` as well since I am able to serve pages using manual coding of a `wsgi` app.

I tried the suggested method for the `ImportError: No module named web` error message on the `web.py` documentation http://webpy.org/install#apachemodwsgi , i.e., adding:

```
abspath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(abspath)
os.chdir(abspath)

import web
```

I also added the `Files` tag suggested in the http.conf file which seems redundant since I have the `htdocs` dir set up already, but anyway. My `httpd.conf` file is below, I have restarted apache and am still getting the import error message.

```
ServerRoot "/home/usr1/webapps/test/apache2"

LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/usr1/webapps/test/logs combined
DirectoryIndex index.py
DocumentRoot /home/usr1/webapps/test/htdocs
ErrorLog /home/usr1/webapps/test/apache2/logs/error_test.log
KeepAlive Off
Listen 21708
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 5
WSGIDaemonProcess test processes=5 python-path=/home/usr1/webapps/test/lib/python3.1 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup test
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On

<Directory /home/usr1/webapps/test/htdocs>
    AddHandler wsgi-script .py
</Directory>

<Files /home/usr1/webapps/test/htdocs/index.py>
   SetHandler wsgi-script
   Options ExecCgi FollowSymLinks
</Files>
```

Comment: You can log your sys.path and check if this module in this path. And also it would be cool if you show what in wsgi-script.py. And also compare what version of python your shell use and your apache use (as I can see apache use python 3.1)

Comment: @DenisNikanorov: OK, so the httpd.conf was generated by my webhost and yes the python3.1 is different to my shell (2.6). So, I changed that and now i'm getting a `ImportError: No module named utils` (that web.py imports) :S. I can't seem to find the `wsgi-script` anywhere that I have access to. Is this something I need to contact my host about?

Comment: I meet a same error as you. Does your program error fixed ? How it fixed ?? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your apache mod_wsgi seems to be compiled with python 3, that is not supported by web.py.

Your apache conf seems a lot like the one I have on Webfaction, if there is an installer for mod_wsgi with python 2.7, you have to choose it instead of python 3.

This is what my typical conf looks like:

```
ServerRoot "/home/username/webapps/projectname/apache2"

LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/username/logs/user/access_projectname.log combined
ErrorLog /home/username/logs/user/error_projectname.log
KeepAlive Off
Listen 21708
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
WSGIPythonOptimize 2
ThreadsPerChild 5
WSGIDaemonProcess projectname processes=5 threads=1
WSGIPythonHome /home/username/lib/python2.7 # your python home dir where libraries are installed
WSGIProcessGroup projectname
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/webapps/projectname/htdocs/code.py/
Alias /static /home/username/webapps/projectname/htdocs/static
```

And this is example code.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
else:
    application = app.wsgifunc()
```

Comment: How do you map urls with that code.py if you import `app` directly? as opposed to `app = web.application(urls, globals())` ?

Comment: I init app in another module and import it in code.py, and I use web.autoapplication where controllers specify their urls (http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/apps/auto) but this is out of scope of this question